# Captcha image is not working

Tags: visualforce, web2lead

```
<section class="form-row">
<label style="line-height:normal;">Please enter the characters you see on the image:</label>
<div class="formfield"> 
<img src="http://www.aress.com/captcha.php"/>
<input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha" value=" "  class="textfld" />
</div>
</section>
```

I am using captcha into my web to lead form. But the image is not displayed in browsers.

Comment: Utkarsha, please add the console log from the dev tools

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with trusted domains.

You need to add `http://www.aress.com/` to your trusted Remote Sites.

Go to: **Setup** > **Security Controls** > **Remote Sites Settings**  and click '**New Remote Site**'

Hope it helped.